# Excluding Numbers for Sieve of Sundaram

Tags: haskell, sieve

I'm working on implementing the [Sieve of Sundaram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram).

The first step is to get a list of Integer's such that:

> i, j are Natural Numbers, 1 <= i <= j
>
> i + j + 2*i*j <= n

Here's my function. It's supposed to generate a list of tuples of all `(i, j)`'s that match the above
restrictions.

```
numsToRemove :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
numsToRemove n = [ (i, j) | i <- [1..n], j <- [1..n], i <= j, i >= 1, j >= 1, 
                            i * j + 2*i*j <= n]
```

But I'm getting non-primes in my answer. Excluding my other work, I think that I'm making a mistake in generating this list of Integers.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function checks for `i * j + 2*i*j <= n` but your definition asks for `i + j + 2*i*j <= n`. There is a `*` that should have been a `+`.

Comment: thanks for catching my mistake! however, when running `numsToRemove 100`, and then doing `(toList . foldr (\(x,y) acc -> insert x $ insert y acc) empty)`, I get `[1..33]` as the result...

Comment: Why do you think thats wrong? Its what I would expect from the restriction you gave in your question.

Comment: well, once I get `[1..33]` as the result, then it's certainly not right if I exclude all of those numbers, no?

Comment: @KevinMeredith, The sieve removes the *results* of the calculation `i + j + 2ij`, not the `i`s and `j`s that generated them.